# ASP.NET Core web application running as a Linux service does not stop properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, systemd

I created a simple ASP.NET Core web application to run as a service on a Linux Ubuntu machine. When I run `systemctl start webapp.service` to start the application, it starts fine. However, when I run `systemctl stop webapp.service` to stop it, the command freezes for a long time and eventually times out. Looking at the application's stdout while it's stopping shows that it doesn't get past the `await this.app.StopAsync()` statement. Here's the output:

```
Nov 21 08:59:57 LinxServer systemd[1]: Stopping WebApp...
Nov 21 08:59:57 LinxServer dotnet[6746]: info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Nov 21 08:59:57 LinxServer dotnet[6746]:       Application is shutting down...
```

It's supposed to write "Stopped" after `StopAsync()` returns, which doesn't happen.

However, when I run the application directly using the command `dotnet WebApplication1.dll`, it starts fine and when I press Ctrl+C, it shuts down as expected:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
Stopping...
Stopped.
```

Here is the application code:

```
await Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Application>();
    })
    .UseSystemd()
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();


class Application : IHostedService
{
    private WebApplication app;

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options => options.ListenAnyIP(8010));
        this.app = builder.Build();

        this.app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

        await this.app.StartAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Started.");
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping...");
        await this.app.StopAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped.");
    }
}
```

Here's the content of the Systemd service unit configuration file:

```
[Unit]
Description=WebApp

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=dotnet WebApplication1.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/webapp
KillSignal=SIGINT
User=myuser
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas?

Edit: As suggested, I tried the following for `Program.Main()` as well (`Application` class unchanged):

```
using var host = Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Application>();
    })
    .UseSystemd()
    .Build();
host.Start();
host.WaitForShutdown();
```

The behavior is the same as before .

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targetting .NET 6

Answer (score 1):

You have here a long explanation of the host shutdown lifecycle:  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/docs/HostShutdown.md.
When u do `systemctl stop` it calls `Environment.Exit` and `Environment.Exit != CTRL+C` .
Add to your code `host.WaitForShutdown();` You have here a short general example that might help u.

```
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

  ......

 using (IHost host = builder.Build())
    {
        host.Services.GetRequiredService<OtherService>();
        host.Start();            
        host.WaitForShutdown();
        Console.WriteLine("Ran cleanup code inside using host block.");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this. The behavior is the same . See the edit in the question.